# In RFC2822, what is the difference between a `mailbox-list` and a `address-list`?

Tags: email, rfc2822

[RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) defines the following Address Specification types:

```
address         =       mailbox / group

mailbox         =       name-addr / addr-spec

name-addr       =       [display-name] angle-addr

angle-addr      =       [CFWS] "<" addr-spec ">" [CFWS] / obs-angle-addr

group           =       display-name ":" [mailbox-list / CFWS] ";"
                        [CFWS]

display-name    =       phrase

mailbox-list    =       (mailbox *("," mailbox)) / obs-mbox-list

address-list    =       (address *("," address)) / obs-addr-list
```

I've gone over the spec several times and can find no functional or actual difference between the `mailbox-list` and the `address-list`. What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is an "address" can be a "group".
A group might be:

```
undisclosed-recipients: ;
```

for example (as seen on Bcc's, for example).